# How to get nvidia-driver-390 on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: nvidia

Dell Latitude 6530 comes with Nvidia Quatro 5200M
23.10 does not offer v390.
According to Nvidia, I can install 535, or the latest driver.
When I try any 400 ...535 driver, it tells me that this hardware is supported by 390.

Ubuntu 23.10 has no nvidia-driver-390 package.

Comment: Looks like you can still download it from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/196213/en-us/ but whether it will still install into Ubuntu 23.10 is another story.

Comment: If you want to use that driver with Ubuntu, you'll have to install 20.04 and use the original kernel series only, not the HWE kernel. No later version of Ubuntu supports it in my experience.  Anything later than that, you have to use nouveau. I have an old PC with a GT 730 card.

Comment: Yes, 390 from Nvidia fails to install for the 6.5.x kernel.

Comment: By the way, the link I supplied above is for the driver that NVIDIA states is for your card.  I couldn't find where they stated that the 535 driver would work for it.  Like what @OrganicMarble posted above if you want to stick with the old hardware and a newer OS you will have to use the nouveau driver.

Comment: Your link was good, but failed to compile - installing anyting >390 and <=535 gives a console warning that the GPU is unsupported/ignored by given driver.
Noveau works - but then the HDMI output is dead.  
I worked aroud the problem by ordering a Lenovo P15

Comment: Contrary to what @OrganicMarble said, I had it working fine with my 4200 card in 22.04, 22.10 and 23.04. It was the upgrade to 23.10 that killed it.

Comment: @LiamProven I tested 22.04 with my GT 730 and it definitely did not work. Perhaps your card is newer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have 2 Thinkpads with discrete GPUs that need driver v390: a Core i7 T420 and a Core i7 W520. Both worked fine with Optimus and Prime offloading until Mantic and kernel 6.5. The GPU in the T420 is a Quadro NVS 4200M, and in the W520 a NVIDIA® Quadro® 2000M. As they are built in GPUs, I can't replace them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Driver version 470 is also supported for GT 730 as per NVIDIA's version. Have you tried it? I also have a GT 730 and I am facing issue.

Comment: @Mayank at this point I don't remember specifically if I tried that driver. If it was not available in the Ubuntu repos, I certainly didn't. My memory is that I tried all the drivers offered up by `ubuntu-drivers` and nothing worked but nouveau. But on 20.04 with the original kernel, I can still run the 390 driver.

Comment: Just to chime in, at work I ran until recently a 2015-ish PC on an Ubuntu-22.04 with HWE enabled. However, yesterday I ran into the issue that the 6.5.0 kernel and the nvidia-390 driver stopped working together. After I read more into this, it's a bit surprising that I was able to run my system that long. Thankfully, I have a newer PC on hand, so I changed over rather than needing to try to disable hwe or to downgrade to 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

To get it - some additional work is necessary. Probably quite extensive work. The legacy drivers were created to support certain linux kernel levels. The kernel is evolving all the time and kernel API is changing. That's why the driver created for kernel 5.x may not compile under 6.x which is the case of NVIDIA.

I'm going to have a closer look at it - however I can't promise anything...

Comment: I have managed to compile and install the driver. However whole environment seems to be not working fully properly. I need to investigate it a bit more, before posting a patch file.

Comment: Thanks, it may be useful for others, I bought a Lenovo T15 to workaround the issue.